# Child overlapping its parent's sibling on hover

Tags: css, hover, overlap

So, here's the first `div`:

```
<div id="parent">
<a>
<div>
<img />
<h3 id="important_text">text</h3>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

The second `div` structure is more or less the same...

```
<div id="sibling">
<a>
<div>
<img />
<h3 id="important_text_n2">text</h3>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

What I want:
When I hover `#parent`, I want `#important_text` (just the `h3#important_text`, not the whole `div`!) to overlap the `#sibling` (his child `img` actually). And when I am NOT hovering `#parent`, I want the `#sibling` to overlap `#parent`.

I've tried it with `z-index`, but I just can not get `#important_text` to overlap its parent's sibling (`#sibling`).

---

EDIT:

Used (not working CSS):

```
#parent {
z-index: 5;
}
#sibling {
z-index: 15;
}
/* option 1 */
#parent:hover a div h3 {
    z-index: 20;
}
/* option 2 ... here I wanted to decrease the sibling img's z-index to a value between #parent and #important_text, but I didn't work either. */
```

Comment: Can you provide the CSS you have used?

Comment: Hi I will be glad to help you but please show more code. include CSS. you can use this FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/fFnfZ/ I have started for you.

Comment: Can you explain or show us visually what you are expecting, or what sort of effect you are trying to create?  There may be a better way than what you are trying.

Comment: I've posted a sample of the CSS used in the OP.

Comment: what are the sizes of your divs? (width / height)

Comment: we need more information. why would they overlap? we need sizes. Please update the FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/fFnfZ/1/

Comment: This image is probably the most illustrative.

http://shrani.si/f/22/Bw/ifAKSHM/soexample1.jpg

Also, the image was taken when hovering #parent.

Answer (score 0):

Give the H3 element a position absolute. Example:

CSS:

```
h3{
   position:absolute;
   margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: you can also achieve this with Javascript. Check out the FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/fFnfZ/3/

Comment: This isn't what I want.

This overlaps the parent (which it already does)... I want it to overlap the SIBLING of the parent. The positioning is fine, the "layers" are fuc*ed up, and I can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the fiddle a bit (the positionings MUST stay absolute). When you hover #parent, the h3 bg goes yellow. What I want is, that the yellow OVERLAPS #sibling. Now it's UNDER #sibling, but I want it to be ABOVE it. Looking at the code, the yellow should visally expand for 20px "into" the #sibling. I hope you understand...

Comment: so when you hover the #parent, you want the yellow part to animate  20px in width, overlapping the next element?

Comment: No no..

The #parent width is 120px, and the #sibling width is 100px.
BUT as the #sibling's position is absolute, and left: 100px, the whole #parent div is not shown (20px is "cut off", cause it OVERLAPS #parent). What I want: When I hover #parent, the #important_text shows it's full width (120px), and is not hidden under #sibling anymore.